# EF returns incorrect rows

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a simple query:

```
IEnumerable<AmountChangeDocumentItemExtended> GetItemsByHeaderId(Guid headerId){
    var results = (from item in _context.AmountChangeDocumentItems
                   where item.HeaderId == headerId
                   select new AmountChangeDocumentItemExtended
                   {.....}).ToArray();
    return results;
}
```

It returns 0 rows, but when i get rows using plain query (ExecuteStoreQuery<>()) i receive actual data.

```
_context.ExecuteStoreQuery<AmountChangeDocumentItem>(@"SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.AmountChangeDocumentItems i
WHERE i.HeaderId = '201dae45-64a6-4b49-b801-c8fb20165ee5'");
```

i don't understand, why the first method not work?

1. For any another guid both methods returns correct rows...
2. In first case i don't see any income queries in my SQL Server profiler...

**UPD**:
Trace string:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[HeaderId] AS [HeaderId], 
[Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion], 
[Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
[Extent1].[PriceCalculatorVersion] AS [PriceCalculatorVersion], 
[Extent1].[FirstSupplierPrice] AS [FirstSupplierPrice], 
[Extent1].[NonTaxablePart] AS [NonTaxablePart], 
[Extent1].[SupplierTaxRate] AS [SupplierTaxRate], 
[Extent1].[SupplierInterestRate] AS [SupplierInterestRate], 
[Extent1].[RetailTaxRate] AS [RetailTaxRate], 
[Extent1].[RetailInterestRate] AS [RetailInterestRate], 
[Extent1].[RetailPrice] AS [RetailPrice], 
[Extent2].[AgentCode] AS [AgentCode], 
[Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[ItemOrder] AS [ItemOrder], 
[Extent1].[Discount] AS [Discount], 
[Extent1].[ExpectedRetailFinalPriceTotal] AS [ExpectedRetailFinalPriceTotal], 
[Extent4].[BarCodeString] AS [BarCodeString], 
[Extent4].[Name] AS [Name1], 
[Extent4].[CountryOfOrigin] AS [CountryOfOrigin], 
[Extent4].[UnitOfMeasureCode] AS [UnitOfMeasureCode], 
[Extent5].[ShortName] AS [ShortName], 
[Extent6].[IsFractional] AS [IsFractional], 
[Extent1].[CheckId] AS [CheckId], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[CheckId] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Extent7].[Number] END AS [C1], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[CheckId] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Extent7].[Sum] END AS [C2],
[Extent1].[AlternateBarCode] AS [AlternateBarCode], 
[Extent1].[AlternateBarCodeCoeff] AS [AlternateBarCodeCoeff], 
[Extent1].[PalmInitialAmount] AS [PalmInitialAmount], 
[Extent1].[PalmInitialRetailPrice] AS [PalmInitialRetailPrice], 
[Extent1].[PalmOutAmount] AS [PalmOutAmount], 
[Extent1].[PalmOutRetailPrice] AS [PalmOutRetailPrice]
FROM       [dbo].[AmountChangeDocumentItems] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CurrentSuppliers] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[ProductCode] = [Extent2].[ProductCode]) AND ([Extent1].[ProductVersion] = [Extent2].[ProductVersion])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Agents] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[AgentCode] = [Extent3].[Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent1].[ProductCode] = [Extent4].[InternalCode]) AND ([Extent1].[ProductVersion] = [Extent4].[Version])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UnitsOfMeasure] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[UnitOfMeasureCode] = [Extent5].[Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UnitsOfMeasure] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[UnitOfMeasureCode] = [Extent6].[Code]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CheckItems] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent1].[CheckId] = [Extent7].[Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[HeaderId] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: Does this work: `var headerId = Guid.Parse("201dae45-64a6-4b49-b801-c8fb20165ee5"};`?

Comment: Also, are you sure your code is using single quotes on that first line?

Comment: @DavidG: yes, i'm sure. I updated the code to the actual version from my solution.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the SQL that is being generated?

Comment: @DavidG: how can i see SQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework

Comment: Though you will need to remove the `ToArray()` (is it even needed anyway?)

Comment: @DavidG: See UPD. Its a full trace string, but i don't know where is "@p__linq__q" parameter...

Comment: `@p__linq__q` is just the name of the parameter being passed in, in this case the Guid. That's a fairly complex SQL, what does the entity code for `AmountChangeDocumentItem` look like?

Comment: My guess here is the you have a referential integrity problem. For example, does `AmountChangeDocumentItem.ProductCode` exist in `CurrentSuppliers.ProductCode`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my edmx model: i have incorrect association multiplier (1 - 1 insted of 1 - 0..1), so EF generate INNER JOIN insted of LEFT JOIN.